# Change instantiated gameobject's prefab in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm wondering if it is possible to change instantiated gameobject's prefab, without creating a new game object.
for example,
`GameObject block = Instantiate (blockPrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity, transform);`

I want to change the block's prefab to another prefab (in a different line),
is it possible? If so, how?
Thanks

Comment: i guess it depends on exactly why you would want to change it for a different prefab.. there are many things you can do, eg strip properties off the current one by replacing them with stuff from a new...

Comment: The Player reaches a new level, so the blocks change their position accordingly, but the blocks' prefab should change aswell, but I couldn't manage to change the blocks' prefab.

Comment: Delete the old prefab, and add another prefab in the same place. This is even easier if you are just replacing the visual part of an object. Have a gameobject containing all the important scripts for the object. Attach the prefab to it. When you need to switch, delete the old prefab and add a new one in the same place.

Comment: Have the visible part as a child, then you can swap it out as much as you like

Answer (score 0):

You just need to store the references for the different prefabs, and then change the reference used in your `Instantiate()` call.

1. Create the two prefabs in the editor (obviously).
2. In script, have something like `public GameObject[] prefabs = new GameObject[2]();`
3. Before your `Instantiate()` call, have your prefab selection and condition logic:

   ```
   var prefabIndex = 0;
   if(yourCondition = true) prefabIndex = 1;
   //... = Instantiate(...)
   ```
4. In your `Instantiate()` call, use the prefabs array and prefab index as a switch: `Instantiate(prefabs[prefabIndex])`

---

Edit:
Based on your comments that...

> (...) the block's prefab should change as well (...)

If the overall structure of a block remains the same, and only a few properties are changed (like color, or HP, for example), it might be a good idea to look into `ScriptableObject`s. Make ***one*** prefab that simply *applies different configurations to the object on spawn based on a `ScriptableObject` reference*.

The process is similar to what I describe above, but avoids the overhead and some pitfalls related to having a completely new `GameObject` prefab in your assets when all you need are a few presets for a few properties.

Comment: I thought the OP was trying to given already instantiated options and replacing them with a different option but without needing, a bit like say polymorphing..

Comment: @BugFinder Maybe. If that's the case, the question might be confusing as it's currently posed. My edit related to `ScriptableObject` might unintentionally be a solution to that issue anyway. It also avoids having to `Destroy` the object or a child of it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it it's possible without destroying the gameobject and creating a new one.
You can Instantiate all of your GameObjects and then use the SetActive method, but it can become quite heavy.

Look at this script : [ReplaceSelection](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ReplaceSelection) maybe it can help you